# Android: setRequestProperty function of URLConnection, what does this method do?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Although I know that StackOverflow has already [setRequestProperty function of HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334920/setrequestproperty-function-of-httpurlconnection) question, I really don't understand what this method does. I cannot ***"step into"*** it (F7) when debugging. I pressed Ctrl-B to view the method's body, but it only has the following code:

```
public void setRequestProperty(String field, String newValue) {
        checkNotConnected();
        if (field == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("field == null");
        }
    }
```

and `checkNotConnected`:

```
private void checkNotConnected() {
        if (connected) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
        }
    }
```

I mean that where is the code that puts the value to the field? Any explanation is appreciated.

**UPDATE (2015/08/08):**
I have found the way to view its implementation. Since it's abstract, must use Ctrl-Alt-B instead of Ctrl-B to view.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty

Comment: @AndoMasahashi: thanks, but only description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are accessing the wrong way, or have some kind of protected code...

The original function is this:

```
/**
 * Sets the general request property. If a property with the key already
 * exists, overwrite its value with the new value.
 * ...
 */
public void setRequestProperty(String key, String value) {
    if (connected)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException ("key is null");

    if (requests == null)
        requests = new MessageHeader();

    requests.set(key, value);
}
```

Where `requests.set(key, value)` do what you're asking for :)!

Answer (score 1):

this is back source code of setRequestProperty()

Sets the general request property. If a property with the key already exists, overwrite its value with the new value.

NOTE: HTTP requires all request properties which can legally have multiple instances with the same key to use a comma-seperated list syntax which enables multiple properties to be appended into a single property.

Parameters:

key the keyword by which the request is known (e.g., "accept").
value the value associated with it.

Throws:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException`

if already connected
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

if key is null
See also:
getRequestProperty(java.lang.String)

```
 public void setRequestProperty(String key, String value) {
    if (connected)
       throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
   if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException ("key is null");

    if (requests == null)
        requests = new MessageHeader();

   requests.set(key, value);
   }
```

[Source Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/net/URLConnection.java#URLConnection.setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to view its implementation. Since it's abstract, must use `Ctrl-Alt-B` instead of `Ctrl-B` to view.

[image: View abstract method's implementation]

And the back source code of `setRequestProperty` as the following (inside jre\lib\rt.jar):

```
public void setRequestProperty(String var1, String var2) {
        if(this.connected) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
        } else if(var1 == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("key is null");
        } else {
            if(this.isExternalMessageHeaderAllowed(var1, var2)) {
                this.requests.set(var1, var2);
            } 
        }
    }
```