# Android HttpURLConnection methods stubbed out in API 23?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am attempting to use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in an Android Studio project using API 23 as my compile SDK version.  I've been having a difficult time troubleshooting until I opened it up to view the source code.  Looking through some of the methods, they seem to be stubbed out or incomplete.  As an example, for the method `HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()` I see:

```
/**
 * Returns an input stream from the server in the case of an error such as
 * the requested file has not been found on the remote server. This stream
 * can be used to read the data the server will send back.
 *
 * @return the error input stream returned by the server.
 */
public InputStream getErrorStream() {
    return null;
}
```

And there are several other examples of methods that don't seem to do what they're supposed to.  Was this a change to the API that is documented somewhere?  Am I taking crazy pills?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Ctrl-B`, use `Ctrl-Alt-B`, then choose the `HttpUrlConnection` from `sun.net.www.protocol.http` (as the screenshot below), you will find its detailed implementation:

```
public InputStream getErrorStream() {
        if(this.connected && this.responseCode >= 400) {
            if(this.errorStream != null) {
                return this.errorStream;
            }

        if(this.inputStream != null) {
            return this.inputStream;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

[image: Implementation of getErrorStream]

Comment: Thanks, did you have to add that as a dependency?  I can't seem to find it as part of the Android SDK.

Comment: No, just a new default project :)

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.httpurlconnection"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
`

Comment: sun.net.* package was not included by default in my dependencies.  Based on your picture I copied the "rt.jar" file in the Java JDK directory into my projects "libs" folder and it worked!

Comment: It's really strange! IMO, you can check your Android Studio configuration or try reintall it. I just need to create a new project, declare HttpUrlConnection, call .getErrorStream, then press Ctrl-Alt-B.

Comment: How about your projects with API22 or lower? It works for all of my projects.

Comment: You know, I had [a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872868/android-setrequestproperty-function-of-urlconnection-what-does-this-method-do) looks like yours before, you can take a look.